# How to Build a Vu meter with LEDs?

Tags: audio, alsa

The following [code](https://github.com/andrebispo5/VumeterRasPi/blob/master/vumeter.py) is a python code for a Vu meter with Raspberry Pi

```
import alsaaudio as alsa
import time
import audioop
import math
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


def ON(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
    return

def OFF(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
    return 

def POWERGPIO(p7,p11,p13,p15,p12,p16,p18,p22):
    if(p7):
        ON(7)
    else:
        OFF(7)
    if(p11):
        ON(11)
    else:
        OFF(11)
    if(p13):
        ON(13)
    else:
        OFF(13)
    if(p15):
        ON(15)
    else:
        OFF(15)
    if(p12):
        ON(12)
    else:
        OFF(12)
    if(p16):
        ON(16)
    else:
        OFF(16)
    if(p18):
        ON(18)
    else:
        OFF(18)
    if(p22):
        ON(22)
    else:
        OFF(22)
    return

def SETGPIO(d):
    if(d == 'a'):
        POWERGPIO(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    elif(d == 'b'):
        POWERGPIO(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    elif(d == 'c'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    elif(d == 'd'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
    elif(d == 'e'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
    elif(d == 'f'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
    elif(d == 'g'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
    elif(d == 'h'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)
    elif(d == 'i'):
        POWERGPIO(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    return
print "##############################"
print "# Waiting for a song to play #"
print "##############################"

inp = alsa.PCM(alsa.PCM_CAPTURE, alsa.PCM_NORMAL, 'hw:Loopback,1,0')
out = alsa.PCM(alsa.PCM_PLAYBACK, alsa.PCM_NORMAL, 'plughw:0,0')

inp.setchannels(2)
inp.setrate(44100)
inp.setformat(alsa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
inp.setperiodsize(320)

out.setchannels(2)
out.setrate(44100)
out.setformat(alsa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
out.setperiodsize(320)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)

status = 1

lo = 10000
hi = 32000

log_lo = math.log(lo)
log_hi = math.log(hi)

while True:
    l,data = inp.read()
    if l:
        try:
            d = audioop.max(data, 2)
            vu = (math.log(float(max(audioop.max(data, 2),1)))-log_lo)/(log_hi-log_lo)
            teste = chr(ord('a')+min(max(int(vu*20),0),19))
            if teste != 'a':
                print teste
            if d>0:
                SETGPIO(teste)
                if status:
                    print "Song found now playing!"
                    status = 0      
        except():
            GPIO.cleanup()
            print "GPIO CLEAN"
            print "Program Closed" 
            break
        out.write(data)
```

The Problem is that the program is stuck **Waiting for a song to play**  even if I play a song with VLC, JUK or Browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which code line hangs?

Comment: @CL. at the line : if d>0 inside the while loop, d is always equal to Zero.

Comment: Are you sure you're playing to the loopback device?

Comment: I am not sure. It's the first time I use pyalsaadio. How do I match the device?

Comment: This has nothing to do with pyalsaaudio; you have to configure VLC/JUK/the browser appropriately.

Comment: I changed the output to Alsa Output Audio and the output module to Loopback PCM default. Good news is that it detects the song now. Bad news is that I get this error:   File "vumeter.py", line 116, in <module>
    d = audioop.max(data, 2)
audioop.error: not a whole number of frames